# Qtransform scale and width of pen set in Qpaint of qgraphicsitem

Tags: qt, transform, qgraphicsitem

Hello friends I am resizing and rotating `QGraphicsItem` using `setTransform`-method of `QGraphicsItem`, I am drawing `QGraphicsItem` of any shape in its `paint`-method, when I scale item using `setTransform` method border of `QGraphicsItem` also gets thicker and I am setting name to `QGraphicsItem`, it also gets bigger as per scaling factor. So is there any method by which I could draw the border of item and name given using `drawtext` in paint method remains of same pen width that I am specifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a pen cosmetic with `pen.setCosmetic(true)` and use this pen to draw border. Cosmetic pen's width doesn't depend on applied transformations.

I recommend using `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem` or `QGraphicsTextItem` to draw text in the scene. You can disable text transformation by calling `textItem->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations);`. It may be convinient to make main graphics item the parent of the text item, so that text item is positioned relative to the main item.

Note that reimplementing `QGraphicsItem::paint` is not necessary in most cases because built-in `QGraphicsItem` subclasses satisfy variety of needs.

Comment: Thanks Pavel it satisfies my border issue using  pen.setCosmetic(true)